# the reason why type char can be converted in specifier %d?

Tags: c, char, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

I suddenly noticed that i've used conversion specifier %d with type char although %d takes only type int.

How is it possible?

According to c standard, conversion specifier %d is corresponding to type int argument.
And *if any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification,
the behavior is undefined.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char a= 'A'; // 'A' = 65 in ASCII

    printf("%c\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}

----- output -----
A
65
```

But whenever i compile the code like above , i always get output as intended.

Shouldn't i expect this output always?

Or, IS type char expanded to type int when passed to function's argument? So it can be 65 and i can use specifier `%d` with type char?

Comment: `printf` is taking variadic arguments, and variadic arguments are undergoing default promotions. For `char` it becomes `int`. [6.5.2.2p6 and p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6)

Comment: You will see the same behaviour for `short` values. Or with `float` values which are promoted to `double`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.2.2 7 says:

> … If the expression that denotes the called function [`printf` is that expression] has a type that does include a prototype [it does], the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

`printf` is declared `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`, so, in `printf("%d\n", a);`, the `"%d"` argument corresponds to the `format` parameter, and the `a` corresponds to the `...`, making it part of the trailing arguments. So the default argument promotions are performed on it. These are specified in 6.5.2.2 6:

> …  the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*.

The integer promotions are specified in 6.3.1.1 2:

> … If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*…

Thus your `char` argument `a` is automatically converted to an `int`, so it is the correct type for `%d`.